# Can not Print in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, printdialog

I have such a problem here. I have a window in my WPF project, and have a button, with what I want To print With printer that page. My click event for that button is this.

```
PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();
Window currentMainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;
Application.Current.MainWindow = this;
if ((bool)dlg.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
{
     Application.Current.MainWindow = currentMainWindow; 
}
```

When I click on buton, the Print dialog is popped out. 
Here
[image]
But When clicking on print, nothing happenes, the dialog is just closing, and no results, it is not working not with Adobe PDF, not with ARX CoSign...

What to do ? Thanks

Comment: You have to create a new "print document" or something like that, im on the train atm ill try answer fully when im off, hopes this helps short term

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661034/printing-in-c-sharp-wpf) question to see if the answers help

Comment: what are you actually trying to print?

Comment: @AdityaBokade I am trying to print the Current window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rough working

```
    var printDoc = new PrintDocument()
    var dlg = new PrintDialog()

    If(dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
           printDoc.Document = [doc to print]
           printDoc.Setting = dlg.settings
           PrintDoc.print()
    }
```

Comment: But what is PrintDocument class ? What assembly it uses ? I can't use it. Get error because it does not understand what is PrintDocument

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`

```
PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();
Window currentMainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;

        Application.Current.MainWindow = this;

        if ((bool)dlg.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
        {
            Application.Current.MainWindow = currentMainWindow; // do it early enough if the 'if' is entered
            dlg.PrintVisual(this, "Certificate");
        }
```